# Accessing Shared Single Files from OneDrive C# SDK

Tags: c#, onedrive

I am coding in the [OneDrive C# SDK](https://github.com/OneDrive/onedrive-sdk-csharp), I am trying to find display all the loose files that have been shared with me. I came across [SharedWithMe](https://dev.onedrive.com/drives/shared_with_me.htm) which seems to show a REST way of achieving what I am looking at doing. My question is if this functionality exists also in the OneDrive C# SDK and if so how would you create that query in C#?

Answer (score 0):

According to the OneDrive C# SDK's Github page, the SDK does not support the ability to view files that are specifically shared and not "mounted" so they won't appear when you try to enumerate a drive.

[OneDrive C# SDK' issue](https://github.com/OneDrive/onedrive-sdk-ios/issues/91)

A way around this is to perform a `REST` call to `api.onedrive.com/v1.0/drive/view.sharedWithMe`